# Repopulate Dropdown on Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataBound DropDown control (so it's populated by a query specified in the designer) and I'd like this query to be repopulated when a button is clicked. The DropDown is defined as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="JobRelPhase_DropDown" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMYDATASOURCE" DataTextField="JobRelPhase" 
     DataValueField="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="my_DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="True" style="text-align: center" 
     Width="684px" Font-Bold="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" BackColor="White" 
     ForeColor="Black">
         <asp:ListItem Value="SELECT AN ITEM" disabled="disabled"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>`
```

and the query is defined in `SqlDataSourceMYDATASOURCE`.

EDIT: Here is the function that is called when the button is clicked:

```
protected void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (JobRelPhase_DropDown.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (JobActive())
        {
            SetButton(GenerateButton, false);
            //JobRelPhase_DropDown.SelectedIndex = -1; //to set back to the top of the list
            JobRelPhase_DropDown.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first clear old values from the dropdown and then rebind.

```
JobRelPhase_DropDown.Items.Clear();
```

ie:

```
 protected void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (JobRelPhase_DropDown.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            if (JobActive())
            {
                SetButton(GenerateButton, false);
                //JobRelPhase_DropDown.SelectedIndex = -1; //to set back to the top of the list
                 JobRelPhase_DropDown.Items.Clear();

                JobRelPhase_DropDown.DataBind();
JobRelPhase_DropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("SELECT AN ITEM"));

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That will eliminate my default selection item - is there a way to add it back in manually through my code?

Comment: Perfect, simple as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To repopulate a dropdown when the DropDownID is set, simply call `DataBind()` on it, and it will be rebound.  You would have to call it in the button click handler as in:

```
protected void Button_Click(..)
{
    //Since you have AppendDataBoundItems="true", have to clear list to reset
    JobRelPhase_DropDown.Items.Clear();
    JobRelPhase_DropDown.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: So the function I'm running is one that should remove the item from the list by changing a field in the database (a field that the query checks for to be true), so the item should no longer be in the list when I call DataBind() since it has been changed to false. However, the items are still in the list when I run DataBind().

Comment: I've added the button's click event handler code. Could it be because I've added my own element to the start of the DropDownList, as you can see in my original code?

Comment: Don't you have to `Clear` the items first? I think they are appended instead of replacing the original items.

Comment: Since you have `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`, you have to clear.  Otherwise, if this was False, then you wouldn't have to worry about that.